# unhandled sqlException

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.
>   The label 'Count' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

my query is:

```
SELECT MAX(PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.improvement_rate) disease_tbl INNER
JOIN PatDiseasTreatment_tbl ON disease_tbl.disease_id =
PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.disease_id INNER JOIN  patient_tbl ON
PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.patient_id = patient_tbl.patient_id INNER JOIN
treatment_tbl ON PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.treatment_id =
treatment_tbl.treatment_id WHERE disease_tbl.MDdisease_name = " +
comboBox2 + " AND patient_tbl.age = " + comboBox1;
```

I don't know what is the error and how to solve it.

Comment: I am missing the keyword `FROM`. `SELECT [] FROM some_table INNER JOIN another_table ON some_table.field = another_table.field_2 WHERE something=1 AND something_else=2` would be the basic syntax

Comment: please don't create yet another sql injection exploit. Use parameters instead of `+comboBox1` and `+comboBox2`.

Answer (score 1):

Proper formatting is your friend:

```
SELECT MAX(PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.improvement_rate)
FROM disease_tbl
INNER JOIN PatDiseasTreatment_tbl ON disease_tbl.disease_id =
    PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.disease_id 
INNER JOIN  patient_tbl ON
    PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.patient_id = patient_tbl.patient_id
INNER JOIN treatment_tbl ON PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.treatment_id =
    treatment_tbl.treatment_id
WHERE disease_tbl.MDdisease_name = " +
comboBox2 + " AND patient_tbl.age = " + comboBox1;
```

you didnt have a "FROM"

Comment: `FROM some_table ON` does not work. The FROM part has no `ON`. You might want to put it into the `WHERE`section

Comment: @scones I was half right :/ the FROM was missing before disease_tbl. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.improvement_rate) 
FROM  disease_tbl
INNER JOIN PatDiseasTreatment_tbl ON disease_tbl.disease_id =
    PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.disease_id 
INNER JOIN  patient_tbl ON
    PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.patient_id = patient_tbl.patient_id
INNER JOIN treatment_tbl ON PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.treatment_id =
    treatment_tbl.treatment_id
WHERE disease_tbl.MDdisease_name = " +
comboBox2 + " AND patient_tbl.age = " + comboBox1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ypu need to mention from clause in your select statement.

```
SELECT MAX(PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.improvement_rate) disease_tbl FROM 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME)
INNER JOIN PatDiseasTreatment_tbl ON disease_tbl.disease_id =PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.disease_id INNER JOIN  patient_tbl ON PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.patient_id = patient_tbl.patient_id INNER JOIN treatment_tbl ON PatDiseasTreatment_tbl.treatment_id =treatment_tbl.treatment_id WHERE disease_tbl.MDdisease_name = " + comboBox2 + " AND patient_tbl.age = " + comboBox1;
```